Setting up redirect in header.php (subdirectory to an external website)
I'd like to know how to do this using header.php (WordPress) or any other method. Basically, I want to set up a redirect from a subdirectory page (e.g. "/my-ebook/") to an external website (e.g. Gumroad).
So, when people visit "/my-ebook/", they're redirected to my Gumroad profile page, for example. I know a plugin can do this, but want to know a way to do this without using a plugin. Thank you in advance.

The template_redirect action is probably the most appropriate action to use, but you could probably use an mu-plugin to run as early as possible.
Here's with the template_redirect action (add to your theme's functions.php):
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    if ( empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $redirect = false;

    foreach ( array( '/my-ebook/', '/my-product/' ) as $needle ) {
        if ( str_contains( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $needle ) ) {
            $redirect = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! $redirect ) {
        return;
    }
    
    nocache_headers();
    
    wp_redirect( ... );

    exit;
} );

For an mu-plugin, take out the code within the action's callback and place it in wp-content/mu-plugins/gumroad-redirect.php:
<?php

if ( empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
    return;
}

$redirect = false;

foreach ( array( '/my-ebook/', '/my-product/' ) as $needle ) {
    if ( str_contains( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $needle ) ) {
        $redirect = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ( ! $redirect ) {
    return;
}

nocache_headers();

wp_redirect( ... );

exit;


Sorry, but the first method didn't quite work. Even when I access the home page (root), it gets redirected. I only want "/my-ebook" page to be redirected (no other pages). Thank you in advance again.

My apologies, I had the parameters for str_contains() in the wrong order. I have updated my answer with the correct order.

No problem at all, it has worked, thank you! Just another question if you don't mind. When they're two URLs (e.g. /my-ebook/ and /my-product/) that I want to redirect to a same external page, how do I write it? When I put the same action twice in functions.php by just changing the source URL, somehow only the first action worked (the second one just went back to the home page [root]). Thank you again for your advice.

Updated answer to support multiple search needles.

You can use multiple method for it but here is suggested 2 methods
first for functions.php

function redirect_my_ebook_page() {
    if (is_page('my-ebook')) { // Check if it's the "my-ebook" page
        wp_redirect('https://gumroad.com/your-profile'); // Redirect to Gumroad
        exit(); // Always call exit after wp_redirect
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_my_ebook_page');


And second method is .htaccess
Redirect 301 /my-ebook/ https://gumroad.com/your-profile


Thank you @ashok-kumawat! Going with the first method!

Thanks, please up vote and approve this answer

I'm trying the first method, but it actually didn't work. When I go to /my-ebook, it just goes back to the home page (root)...
